# Add a new row in to grouped table if ID not exit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, ssms, addition

I have a table `Table1` with more than 1000 rows, and it has more than 30 columns. I show only the columns of interest: `ID, relatedID, Name`.

`ID` is the same when I have the same group, `relatedID` is different one person from other and `Name` is the same in all rows that is group name.

Here is an example for what my data looks like:

| ID | relatedID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23 | office |
| 1234 | 56 | office |
| 1234 | 87 | office |
| 999 | 1 | office |
| 999 | 58 | office |
| 876 | 23 | office |

Now I want to add one person in all `ID` group if the person (`relatedID`) does not exist, other column will stay the same no change in them just a new row of a new `relatedID` if this `relatedID` does not exist.

My result should be like:

| ID | relatedID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 23 | office |
| 1234 | 56 | office |
| 1234 | 87 | office |
| 1234 | 1111 | office --here |
| 999 | 1 | office |
| 999 | 58 | office |
| 999 | 1111 | office --here |
| 876 | 23 | office |
| 876 | 1111 | office --here |

I tried to write a code that save data in a new temp table (#t) and then update my original table (Table1), but I don't know how I must continue.

```
SELECT     
    identifier, title,
    (FORMAT(registerDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US')) AS Reg_Date,  
    GetText(ID) AS relatedIDName, --this function has 1111 son input and return person 
    name
INTO 
    #t1
FROM    
    InfoHeap 
INNER JOIN
    ObjProperties op ON objectID = infoHeapID 
INNER JOIN
    InfoHeapCaseType ct ON ct.caseTypeID = InfoHeap.caseTypeID
WHERE    
    moduleID = 100 AND typeID = 199 
    AND registerDate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-12-31'

UPDATE #t1 
SET relatedIDName = CONCAT_WS(',', relatedIDName, 'Dejana') --1111
WHERE relatedIDName NOT LIKE '%Dejana%'

-- here I can't continue
-- INSERT into Table1
-- SELECT Distinct t1.*, relatedPropID = 1111 --Related propID 
-- WHERE relatedPropID NOT LIKE 1111
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the required rows by using `distinct` as the following:

```
select distinct id, 1111 as relatedID, name
  from tbl_name
```

Then use a left join to insert only the rows that does not exists in your table as the following:

```
with t as
(
  select distinct id, 1111 as relatedID, name
  from tbl_name
)
insert into tbl_name
select t.id, t.relatedID, t.name
from t left join tbl_name tbl
on t.id = tbl.id and 
   t.relatedID = tbl.relatedID and 
   t.name = tbl.name
where  tbl.relatedID is null
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LeEGq-HO)

Comment: After I save the new tb1_name, that is temporar table how I can move the update to orginal table

Comment: Here, tbl_name is the original table and I used a CTE t instead of using a temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Adding missing identifier from the input table `t1` to groups of `Table1` using a join on NOT EXISTS

```
select ID, relatedID, Name
into Table1
from  ( 
 values
       (1234, 23, 'office'),                                                                               
       (1234, 56, 'office'),                                                                                               
       (1234, 87, 'office'),                                                                                              
       (999,   1, 'office'),                                                                                                  
       (999,  58, 'office'),                                                                                             
       (876,  23, 'office') 
) t(ID, relatedID, Name);

with t1 as(
   select 1111 identifier
   union 
   select 87
)
insert into Table1 (ID, relatedID, Name)
select a.ID, c.identifier, a.Name 
from (select distinct ID, Name
      from Table1) a
join t1 c on not exists (
    select 1
    from Table1 b
    where a.ID = b.ID and b.relatedID = c.identifier);

select * 
from table1
order by ID desc, relatedID;
```